# Is mixing do for while loops in Java efficient?

Tags: java

Apart from being able to modify x and y value in ordinary nested for loop separately which can't be done in this mixed do for while loop, could there be any advantageous memory usage or performance efficiency difference?

Ordinary nested for loop:

```
int width = 15, height = 15;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                // do stuff here
            }
```

Example of mixed do for while loop:

```
int y = 0, width = 15, height = 15;
        do for (int x = 0; x++ < width;) {
            // do stuff here
        } while (y++ < height);
```

I found this when reading my very old game engine code from when I started programming.

Comment: It's not going to make any difference either way.  This is not something worth worrying about.

Comment: It's efficient in terms of performance; but it's not efficient in terms of readability.

Comment: Note that those two loops aren't equivalent: in the innermost loop, `x` is 1 greater in the second case than the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the bytecode for the two functions, you'll see that they're almost exactly the same:

```
$ cat test.java
class test {
    public static void forfor() {
        int width = 15, height = 15;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                // do stuff here
            }
    }

    public static void dofor() {
        int width = 15, height = 15, y = 0;
        do for (int x = 0; x++ < width;) {
            // do stuff here
        } while (y++ < height);
    }
}
$ javac test.java
$ javap -c test
  public static void forfor();
    Code:
       0: bipush        15
       2: istore_0
       3: bipush        15
       5: istore_1
       6: iconst_0
       7: istore_2
       8: iload_2
       9: iload_1
      10: if_icmpge     32
      13: iconst_0
      14: istore_3
      15: iload_3
      16: iload_0
      17: if_icmpge     26
      20: iinc          3, 1
      23: goto          15
      26: iinc          2, 1
      29: goto          8
      32: return

  public static void dofor();
    Code:
       0: bipush        15
       2: istore_0
       3: bipush        15
       5: istore_1
       6: iconst_0
       7: istore_2
       8: iconst_0
       9: istore_3
      10: iload_3
      11: iinc          3, 1
      14: iload_0
      15: if_icmpge     21
      18: goto          10
      21: iload_2
      22: iinc          2, 1
      25: iload_1
      26: if_icmplt     8
      29: return
```

The only real difference is that in `forfor`, both conditions are checked at the start of the loop, while in `dofor`, one is checked at the start and one is checked at the end. I cannot think of any performance implications of that bytecode reordering, given that you have exactly the same instructions in the innermost loop body.

That said, I believe the `forfor` method is the better of the two, because:

1. Its intention is obvious
2. It's less bug-prone (see also the comment on this question that found a bug in `dofor`!)
3. If `height` were zero, `dofor` would erroneously still execute one pass of the loop, while `forfor` does the right thing by skipping the outer loop entirely.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your comment.